# Why any normal set is thick?

Tags: combinatorics

Set $S\subset\Bbb{N}$ is normal, if $1_s$ form a $0$-$1$ **normal sequence**, that is for any $0$-$1$ word with length $n$ it has limiting frequency $1/2^n$. Set $A\subset\Bbb{N}$ is thick if $A=\cup_{n=0}^\infty I_n$, $I_n=(a_n,b_n)$, $a_n - b_n\rightarrow\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, i.e. $A$ contains arbitrarily large interval.

But why normal set is thick?

Comment: Your question is not clear. I suppose $S$ is a set, but what kind of set? Also your intervals, are they intervals of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Your definition of *thick set* is not quite correct: $A$ is not necessarily the union of the intervals $I_n$. In fact if that were a requirement, a normal set would *not* be thick, since it has short intervals interspersed amongst those of increasing length.

Comment: @ Brian, yes you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much weaker condition than being a normal $0$-$1$ sequence is containing every (finite) word over that alphabet at least once. In particular this applies to all words consisting of $n$ copies of $1$ (and no instances of $0$) for some $n\in \Bbb N$. That answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much but what do you mean by "ever word"?

Comment: Oops, a typo. "every word". Edited now, and I added "finite" for clarity.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps! I am now clear.